# Do enum constant tags consume memory?

Tags: c, enums

Do `enum` definitions `enum` constants consume memory in C?

For example, as given below

```
enum week { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY };
```

Do enum constants, for example, `SUNDAY` take up memory?

Comment: The rules are no different to any other kind of constant.

Comment: #define constant do not consume memory.

Comment: @KushalDalsania; `const` are not real constants.

Comment: Unless it's compiled out by dead code eliminator or the optimizer, #define constant do consume memory, although it's likely to be in the code section rather than in data section.

Comment: @LieRyan Preprocessor directives like #define have no way to take up memory at runtime unless the #defined symbols are actually used. Preprocessor operations are purely lexical.

Comment: @OllieJones: as I said, unless it's compiled out, it must take up memory. Perhaps I'm being loose about the term "compiled out" here, I was referring to the entire compiler chain including the preprocessor when I said compiled out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions do not take up runtime memory. They obviously take up memory at compile time, but not much.

If you write the following code to declare a variable (in this example `my_weekday`), it will take runtime memory. The number of bytes consumed depends on the compiler, the target machine architecture's alignment rules, and the cardinality of the enumeration.

```
enum week my_weekday { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
                       THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY };
```

If your code assigns a constant to such a variable the constant will occupy space either inline in the code or in a readonly literal pool constructed by the compiler.

```
my_weekday = SUNDAY;
```

If you pass an enum constant (or the address of such a constant) to a function as an actual parameter, it gets allocated space in the call stack. Notice that some topnotch global optimization may be able to use machine registers instead.

Similarly, code space or literal pool space will be allocated for the enum constants if you use a switch-case or conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

No. These are constants and doesn't take any memory nor they have address. In fact `SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY` doesn't exist anywhere in mmemory. But you can check that the type `enum` itself takes a memory of size of an `int` (the choice of type is implementation defined).

Comment: They might take up code space, though (e.g. `if (x == SUNDAY)`, the value needs to be represented somewhere).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; Yes. I understand, but they are not stored in memory. You can't take the address of any of constants.